# How to mark all unread email as read on Hotmail?

Tags: outlook.com

I have around 2,000 emails as unread in Hotmail.

How can I mark all of then as read in one go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's rather easy. You just put a check mark on the box in top left side (just beside 'Show:') of email list. It selects all mails in the view. Then hotmail will provide you an option just above list of mails: "xx items selected. Select everything in your ???? folder". Just click 'Select Everything'. Click upon "Mark As > Read" on the topmost bar. The operation will be done in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Outlook.com, simply right-click the folder you want to mark as read, and click “Mark all as read”.

Comment: This is what I used

Answer (score 0):

Click "Sweep" then "mark folder as unread".

Comment: Perhaps you can add a pic, to give some extra guidance.